# RSS feed settings

Tags: support, rss

I rely on an RSS feed to my mail client to know when something new is posted on OR SE. Unfortunately, edits to old questions or answers (many of which do nothing I can detect to enhance the clarity of the questions or answers) trigger an RSS message. Individually a "false positive" is not a huge deal, but collectively they become a nontrivial waste of time. Is there any way the feed settings can be changed to ignore edits and only alert new posts (questions, answers or comments)?

Comment: I'm not familiar with RSS feeds but you might get some responses on https://meta.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Thanks. I did a search there. It turns out this is a FAQ that pops up every few years. There's at least a partial answer at https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230664/can-there-be-a-feed-web-or-rss-that-ignores-minor-or-all-edits. I'm not sure I can make it work with my mail client (Thunderbird), and I'm not sure it's worth the effort.